# Only log SMS messages without sending outgoing messages in Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

*Scenario*

- I have an app that hooked to a twilio phone number through twilio credentials.

Is there a way to only log the SMS messages that my app is sending to twilio without twilio sending it to any outside number?

Comment: There is no setting within the Twilio API to not send messages aside from using the test credentials (as gipsy has said). I don't understand why you would want the Twilio API to not send messages, unless you're testing. Perhaps I'm missing something, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Twilio test credentials. Then it won't send out the actual sms.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials

Comment: Is there a way to not use the test credentials? like a configuration change that is present in the Twilio online dashboard.